# Pascal Triangle in Ruby

Tags: ruby, iteration

I'm trying to write a method to generate Pascal's triangles as a 2D array. For example:

```
pascal(3) # => [[1],[1,1],[1,2,1]]
```

Here is my code:

```
def pascal n
  pascal = []
  row = [1]
  (1...n).each do |i|
    #first iteration set pascal equal to [[1]] and row to [1,1]
    if i.zero?
      pascal << row
      #sets new value for row for next iteration
      row = [1,1]
    else
      #row generator sets new value for row 
      row = ([0] + row).zip(row + [0]).collect { |a, b| a + b }
      #push row's new value into pascal array
      pascal << row
    end
  end
end
```

I know the row generator works fine, I've tested myself with irb. The output is `1...5`, as if it didn't run.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return value of ruby method is the last thing evaluated. In your case, it's `each`. `each` returns a thing it iterated (the range). You should explicitly return `pascal` array from your method as this seems to be the result you need. Add this line to the end of your method.

```
      pascal << row
    end # end if
  end # end each

  pascal # < this line

end # end method
```

This will make `pascal` the last thing evaluated and, therefore, return value of the method.

JFYI, it seems that your code has broken logic. If we do the abovementioned correction, we get this (which does not match your expectation).

```
pascal(3) # => [[1, 1], [1, 2, 1]]
```

I leave it up to you to debug this. :)

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer, I see why it didn't work, I was too focused on iterations and forgot to return :)

I'll start debugging right away!

Comment: This, BTW, is the exact same bug as in your last question. Idiomatically, you would use `map` instead of `each`, and if you did that, your code would work fine just the way it is.

Comment: Good to know, I tend to forget the difference between each and map/collect. I solved it changing the range to `(1...n+1)`, but I'll use map instead